# How use echo with grep in a Unix shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, echo

I need to use echo with grep in a shell script. Can I use it?

I tried this, but is incorrect:

```
echo Linux: grep "Linux" ~/workspace/ep-exercicios/m1/e2/intro-linux.html | wc -w
```

I need show the message:

```
Linux: (number of Linux word on the document).
```

Example:

```
Linux: 945
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep -o | wc -l` logic from other answer should work on most systems today.

Here is another mechanism using `awk`.

```
awk 'END{print RS " : " NR-1}' RS=Linux ~/workspace/ep-exercicios/m1/e2/intro-linux.html
```

Logic: split the file in records, with record separator = "Linux". In the end, print the record number.

---

**e.g.** for file containing these contents:

> The Linux is a Unix-like and mostly POSIX-compliant computer operating
>   system (OS) assembled under the model of free and open-source software
>   development and distribution. The defining component of Linux is the
>   Linux kernel, an operating system kernel first released on October 5,
>   1991 by Linus Torvalds. The Free Software Foundation uses the name
>   GNU/Linux to describe the operating system, which has led to some
>   controversy

records will be:

1. The
2. is a Unix-like and mostly POSIX-compliant computer operating system (OS) assembled under the model of free and open-source software development and distribution. The defining component of
3. is the
4. kernel, an operating system kernel first released on October 5, 1991 by Linus Torvalds. The Free Software Foundation uses the name GNU/
5. to describe the operating system, which has led to some controversy

Occurrence count of Linux is 4 == last record number - 1.

Comment: I re-iterate the point you've made in the beginning-  `rep -o | wc -l logic from other answer should work on most systems today` & plus1 for your logic

Comment: yup... most (not all) & today were important words in that :D

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep` with `-o` option:

```
printf "%s: %s\n" "Linux : " "$(grep -o "Linux" ~/workspace/ep-exercicios/m1/e2/intro-linux.html | wc -w)"
```

should do it

**grep** manpage says :

> -o, --only-matching
>                 Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,with each such part on a separate output line.

Comment: It would be worth explaining why you used the `-o` option, and also worth noting that it is a GNU `grep` extension not available on all variants of Unix.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thankyou. I was under the impression that grep stands for GNU  Regular Expressions Print. Eye opener indeed !

Comment: Originally, it was a shorthand for `g/re/p`, an `ed` command to 'globally search for regex and print' — where `ed` was the standard editor in the days before `vi` became available.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Oh ! I see :)

Comment: `grep -o` and not `grep -c`, that way you count Linux in the line `Linux and Linux are the systems I use most` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can achieve it by doing slight modification below.

echo "Linux: `grep "Linux" ~/workspace/ep-exercicios/m1/e2/intro-linux.html | wc -w`"