# How do I search a word in Shell Script (Bash)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to search the string "Linux" in a web page, first in case-sensitive, sencond in case-insensitive.

Well, my search will be in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/intro-linux.html

I made the bellow code, but it is not return every words "Linux".

```
echo Linux: $(grep -wc "Linux" ~/workspace/ep-exercicios/m1/e2/intro-linux.html)
```

For example, my code return 405 words, but has 447.

How do it?

Comment: You asked yesterday about this in the question this is now (currently) a duplicate of ([How to use `echo` with `grep` in a Unix shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024647/how-use-echo-with-grep-in-a-unix-shell-script)).  You were told how to do it between the comments and the answers, and why.

Comment: Thats ok, If this quetion is better can I delete that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` counts matching lines, so lines with multiple matches are counted only once.

```
echo "Linux Linux Linux" | grep -woc Linux
1
```

You could use the `-o` flag to generate one line per match, then `wc -l` to count

```
echo "Linux Linux Linux" | grep -o Linux | wc -l
3
```

Comment: This is correct and is basically the answer the OP was given yesterday to his other question — the one this is now a duplicate of.

Comment: See edit, forgot to add the wc flag, pipe the page to grep with cat, or as an argument of grep

Comment: Wonderful, thank so much!