# bash echo does not work after grep returns nothing

Tags: linux, bash, grep, echo

I understand that people generally use grep in Linux command prompt (not in a script). I happen to put grep in a script and run into a strange case. If the grep command returns nothing, the next line echo does not work. Below is the script.

```
grep "abc" /home/testuser/myapp.log
echo "abc"
```

Is this the normal behavior of grep? If yes, why?

Comment: what is the content of the `#!` line at the start of the script? How do you invoke the script? (eg. `bash scriptfile`, `./scriptfile`, etc) What is output of adding `echo $SHELLOPTS` before the `grep` line?

Comment: Try redirecting the output: `grep "abc" /home/testuser/myapp.log > /tmp/stdout 2> /tmp/stderr`  Then see what's in the files - note, though this can change `grep`'s output since it detects if its output is a terminal.  Also, GNU `grep` should support something like `grep --color=never ...` or `grep --color=always ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that `set -e` is enabled in your script.

Normally the exit status of `grep` is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.  Note however, if the -q or --quiet or --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred. In your case, if `abc` is not found in `/home/testuser/myapp.log`, `grep` will return 1.

The `bash` shell will normally execute the next line in your script, i.e. `echo "abc"` even if `grep` returns an exit status of 1. However if `set -e` is enabled, `bash` will not execute any more lines in your script.

From the `bash` manpage:

```
-e      Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a list, or  a  compound  command
        (see  SHELL GRAMMAR above), exits with a non-zero status.  The shell does not exit if the command that fails is
        part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test following the  if  or
        elif  reserved words, part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final &&
        or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with !.  If a
        compound  command  other  than a subshell returns a non-zero status because a command failed while -e was being
        ignored, the shell does not exit.  A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.  This option  ap‐
        plies  to  the  shell  environment  and each subshell environment separately (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT
        above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.
   
        If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being ignored, none of  the  commands
        executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the -e setting, even if -e is set and
        a command returns a failure status.  If a compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a  con‐
        text  where -e is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until the compound command or the command con‐
        taining the function call completes.
```

Comment: Indeed, I have "set -e" in my script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to `echo` with `grep`:

```sh
printf "%s\n" "$(grep -o "abc" /home/testuser/myapp.log)"
```

---

###### References

- [grep man page](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html)
- [How to use echo with grep in a Unix shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024647/how-use-echo-with-grep-in-a-unix-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean by "*the next line echo does not work*"?  Is the `echo` not reached at all?  Does it run but yield a non-zero exit code?  Or do you see `abc` on the output?  Knowing your script will return nothing for the `grep`, and knowing nothing else about the rest of the script, I can say that the script will output nothing on `stdout` for the `grep` command and `abc` on `stdout` for the `echo`.